# Where to ask question about Java API's?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, closed-questions, off-topic

Yesterday, I asked for an API in Java and the question were closed because it was "Off Topic".

I was confused about that because last week I asked for an Animation API in Java and I got an answer without my question being closed or being told it was off topic.

The problem is, both question were about Java API, the first have been answered, but the second is closed.

Why? Does there is a rule that says asking about APIs is off topic?

1. [**First Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838314/animation-apis-for-frames)
2. [**Second Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967816/api-for-sharing-lan-through-wireless)

Comment: If that puts your mind to rest, we'll also close your first question. It just slipped through the cracks.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby: Not necessary, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Recommendation questions are off-topic](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). The one that got closed started with

> I need an API for ...

which made it even clearer that this is only asking for a recommendation.

The other question was just not that obvious and passed because it got only 1 close vote from 5 that are necessary.

To answer your question:

#### Don't ask recommendation questions on *any* SE site.*

On the other hand if you have a question where you are stuck with an specific API function and need help fixing that, then you alre welcome to ask on *Stack Overflow*.

<sub>* There is [a site for software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)</sub>

Comment: +1, Thanks. Then, where is the right place to ask this kinda question(s), please?

Comment: As I said not on any SE site. Look for a forum site on the internet.

Comment: Fair enough, this kinda question have more that one answer, and don't have a final solution. But isn't better to create another SE site for this issues ?\

Comment: See the link to the proposal in my answer? You can commit to that and maybe the site will launch in the future.

Answer (score 5):

We have a help page named: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

If you scroll down on it, you'll find this:

> **Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**
>
> 5. Questions asking us to *recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Your questions were closed as off topic because they were asking for exactly this.

[image: This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." – Marc B, Esoteric Screen Name, Chris, allprog, Benoit]

Comment: +1, Thanks. I didn't notice that, off course, I will read the help page.