# Comment Markup is Broken for Some Reason

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, auto-linking

In [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18044/are-there-any-online-chat-or-online-support-groups-for-full-time-telecommuters) I tried to making the following comment in markup:

> `Hey jk, and welcome to [workplace.se]! The best questions here ask
>   *"practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"* as explained in our [help/dont-ask]. Asking for resources
>   usually isn't a great fit for stack exchange sites [as explained
>   here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198250/). If you could
>   [edit] your question to focus it on an answerable question, such as,
>   *"How can full-time telecommuters overcome feelings of isolation?"* or something similar, you will get much better answers. Thanks in
>   advance!`

This should end up as this:

> [image: Correct]

But it is coming up as this instead:

> [image: Incorrect]

Based on Testing, the following sequence seems to break it:

1. Site Magic Link
2. Italics
3. Edit Link
4. Normal Link
5. Edit Link

Further testing shows that the sequence is more likely:

1. `[help]` -or- `[site.se]` -or- `[edit]`
2. `[help]` -or- `[site.se]` -or- `[edit]`
3. `[normal link](http://whatever.com)`
4. `[edit]`

Italics don't seem to be necessary, just two magic links followed up by a normal link then an edit link. Changing the last edit from edit seems to work fine, and the type of magic links for the first two don't seem to matter much. Haven't tested various types of normal links either.

Comment: Hey jk, and welcome to [workplace.se]! The best questions here ask *"practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"* as explained in our [help/dont-ask]. Asking for resources usually isn't a great fit for stack exchange sites [as explained here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198250/). If you could [edit] your question to focus it on an answerable question, such as, *"How can full-time telecommuters overcome feelings of isolation?"* or something similar, you will get much better answers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Page source excerpt: `stack exchange sites <a href="<a href="http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198250/">meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/198250</a>">as explained here</a>. ` There's a link in that link!

Comment: Hmm, I just reproduced this here (as you can tell `:P`). I have no idea what it's not working...

Comment: **Test without "help/dont-ask" magic link seems to work**: Hey jk, and welcome to [workplace.se]! The best questions here ask
*"practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"* as explained in our . Asking for resources
usually isn't a great fit for stack exchange sites [as explained
here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198250/). If you could [edit] your question to focus it on an answerable question, such as,
*"How can full-time telecommuters overcome feelings of isolation?"* or something similar, you will get much better answers. Thanks in
advance!

Comment: Interesting. I always use magic links to the help center, and never run in to this problem before, so it seems to have been broken recently methinks. Thanks for the testing @Geobits!

Comment: It only seems to happen in particular spots. I tried it in place of the workplace one and it worked fine. It may be tripping on 3 of them rather than that specific one, also. My "edit comment" period of testing ended, but I figured it would be enough for them to go on without me deleting and testing even more.

Comment: 1) [workplace.se] magic link 2) *"italics"* 3) [edit] link 4) [regular link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216047) 5) [edit] edit link

Comment: (as explained here, before magic link) [as explained here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198250/) (magic link) [help/dont-ask] (same again, after magic link) [as explained here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198250/)

Comment: that's a really screwed up bug, I'm on it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Congratulations on finding a new edge case in a class that hasn't been touched since 2011.

Fix rolls out in build rev `2014.1.15.1850` on meta and `.1300` on sites.

Comment: Thank you for the congratulations -- maybe I missed my calling as a QA person. Keep this in mind next time you guys discuss [secret badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213130/implement-secret-badges) (*hint hint*).